# inline-block isn't working as expected with divs

Tags: html, css

I trying to build a Simon game but I'm messing with CSS.

[image: simon game]
<sub>(source: [walmartimages.com](http://i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/dce07b8c-837a/k2-_c8eba155-7ff4-45e8-86ab-704862d4a446.v1.jpg))</sub>

I don't know my mistakes but inline-block isn't working as expected:

```css
    body {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #box {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #333;
        top: 10vh;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #222;
    }
    
    #box .pad {
        width: 240px;
        height: 240px;
        float: left;
        left: 0px;
        border: 5px solid #333;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #222;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    #topLeft {
        background-color: green;
        border-top-left-radius: 100%;
    }
    
    #topRight {
        background-color: red;
        border-top-right-radius: 100%;
        /*right: 0;*/
    }
    
    #bottomLeft {
        background-color: yellow;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    }
    
    #bottomRight {
        background-color: blue;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <body>

        <h1 id="header">freeCodeCamp JS Simon Game</h1>

     <div id="box">
            <div class="pad" id="topLeft"></div>
            <div class="pad" id="topRight"></div>
            <div class="pad" id="bottomLeft"></div>
            <div class="pad" id="bottomRight"></div>

  </div>


    </body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gbs4320m/

I tried to mix things up with different settings and consulted online resources but i couldn't figure out the problem.

Please help!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's a Simon Game? What exactly is your issue? Be specific.

Comment: @PraveenKumar edited. Thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gbs4320m/1/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the position absolute:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 10vh;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #222;
}

#box .pad {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  float: left;
  left: 0px;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #222;
  display: inline-block;
}

#topLeft {
  background-color: green;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
}

#topRight {
  background-color: red;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  /*right: 0;*/
}

#bottomLeft {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
}

#bottomRight {
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">freeCodeCamp JS Simon Game</h1>
<div id="box">
  <div class="pad" id="topLeft"></div>
  <div class="pad" id="topRight"></div>
  <div class="pad" id="bottomLeft"></div>
  <div class="pad" id="bottomRight"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!!! It works! Why?

Comment: inline-block makes element block but operate like inline respect to others. The container width is 500px and 240px each color block, therefore there are two in a row and the third pass to the next. Sorry my english

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are setting various unnecessary `float:left`, `position:absolute`, `left:0px;` which conflicts with `inline-block` or just don't do anything in this scenario.

So let's remove those and get the `#box .pad` definition much simpler:

```
#box .pad {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border: 5px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #222;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #333;
    top: 10vh;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #222;
}

#box .pad {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border: 5px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #222;
    display: inline-block;
}

#topLeft {
    background-color: green;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
}

#topRight {
    background-color: red;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    /*right: 0;*/
}

#bottomLeft {
    background-color: yellow;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
}

#bottomRight {
    background-color: blue;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1 id="header">freeCodeCamp JS Simon Game</h1>

  <div id="box">
    <div class="pad" id="topLeft"></div>
    <div class="pad" id="topRight"></div>
    <div class="pad" id="bottomLeft"></div>
    <div class="pad" id="bottomRight"></div>

  </div>

</body>
```

That gets things in the right order but the segments are showing underneath each other. Why? Because of the way that spaces between `inline-block` elements is handled - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements).

There are various ways around this as described in the answers to that question but the simplest solution in your case is probably just to `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`. This will show the elements next to each other and overflow them onto the next "line" in a similar way to `display:inline-block`, but without the spacing issue:

```
#box .pad {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border: 5px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #222;
    float:left;
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #333;
    top: 10vh;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #222;
}

#box .pad {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border: 5px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #222;
    float:left;
}

#topLeft {
    background-color: green;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
}

#topRight {
    background-color: red;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    /*right: 0;*/
}

#bottomLeft {
    background-color: yellow;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
}

#bottomRight {
    background-color: blue;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1 id="header">freeCodeCamp JS Simon Game</h1>

  <div id="box">
    <div class="pad" id="topLeft"></div>
    <div class="pad" id="topRight"></div>
    <div class="pad" id="bottomLeft"></div>
    <div class="pad" id="bottomRight"></div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `position:relative` for your `#box pad` in CSS.

Here is the updated link https://jsfiddle.net/gbs4320m/2/

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `position absolute:`and it works just fine.